# Python editor that can connect to remote environment?

Tags: python, ide, editor

I set up an interactive python environment in an application. I can input commands and they will execute inside it, having access to the variables that live there.

The problem is that I coded a half-assed editor that allows only that. It doesn't have command history, code completion etc, because I didn't code a full IDE. However, I would like to be able to write code in that environment with a fancy editor.

The way I think it can work out is that an editor will have an interface/protocol for remote python sessions, and I will just have to implement a server in my application (instead of the simple editor) and be able to connect and run code.

I can implement any interface or protocol that I have to, but I can't find an IDE that has such a protocol defined (or an easy way to plug an extension that will serve as the client side).

Essentially, I want a python editor that has an option to call a function x whenever a command (can be multiline) finished typing, and another function y when an autocomplete request occurs.
I checked out some editors but couldn't find such a feature. Does anyone know of such a thing? It actually doesn't have to be a python editor, just support the hooks that i need.

Thanks!

Comment: I plan to write some not-so-trivial scripts in that environment, and there is no way that I'm able to instantiate and editor there (can't even get window handles sadly) so its either writing a full IDE or doing this. This will be much cheaper if a compatible editor exists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try integrating PyCrust into your application? See this SO question

[Embedding a Python shell inside a Python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813571/embedding-a-python-shell-inside-a-python-program)

[rpyc](http://rpyc.wikidot.com/) sounds like something which could be useful to you. rpyc added support for IronPython in their [latest release](https://github.com/tomerfiliba/rpyc/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst). [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) supports rpyc. Maybe this is the combo you are looking for?

Comment: I am running with IronPython instead of regular python, which means that wxWidgets is unavailable (no CPython bindings), so PyCrust will be impossible. I really have zero access to any GUI/windowing library from my running environment, which is why I want to inject commands via a listening socket/pipe.